# More verbose mode for included files in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, debian, log4cplus

I am trying to compile someone else's project. I already managed to build it under windows, which means it's compilable, but now I'm struggling on Linux. Specifically I am getting errors for one file:

```
#ifndef _LOGGER_H_2011_27_02_ 
#define _LOGGER_H_2011_27_02_ 

//  logger
#include <log4cplus/logger.h>
#include <iomanip>

#define LOG_TRACE(logger, msg) LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(logger, \
    "[@" << std::hex << (size_t)this << "] " << std::dec << msg);

#define LOG_DEBUG(logger, msg) LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(logger, \
    "[@" << std::hex << (size_t)this << "] " << std::dec << msg);

// I erased repetitive declarations for WARN, FATAl etc...
```

The code itself makes no sense to me, expression `"[@" <<` is kind of wild, but it doesn't matter, it should compile. The errors I get are:

```
source/repository/../query/../loader/../common/logger.h:30:64: error: ‘LOG4CPLUS_ERROR’ was not declared in this scope
     "[@" << std::hex << (size_t)this << "] " << std::dec << msg);
```

And also:

```
source/repository/Repository.cpp: In member function ‘void W3TTServer::Repository::cleanupSessions()’:
source/repository/Repository.cpp:82:64: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [33]’ and ‘long int’ to binary ‘operator<<’
  LOG4CPLUS_TRACE(logger, "Cleaning up inactive sessions..." << sessionCleanupTimer);
```

I enabled the verbose mode but it's a joke, really, all I got is list of include directories:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/ssl/include
 /usr/include/c++/4.9
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9
 /usr/include/c++/4.9/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The log4cplus library is installed in `/usr/include/log4cplus/` and since there was no error about missing header file, I assume `<log4cplus/logger.h>` loaded just fine. To verify this, I need a list of included files to see whether the location was correct.

How can I get a list of included files in GCC?

Comment: You could try adding `#include <log4cplus/loggingmacros.h>`

Comment: @Galik Wow thanks, the errors are gone! :)

Comment: You can avoid having to define own macros by using the [`NDCContextCreator`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1NDCContextCreator.html) and the [`%x` formatter with `PatternLayout`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PatternLayout.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the [`-H` (preprocessor) option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) to `g++`, generally by adding that in your `Makefile` e.g. adding

```
CXXFLAGS += -H
```

at an appropriate place of your `Makefile`

You might simply try `make CXX='g++ -H -Wall'` on the terminal.

If you type `g++` in your terminal, add `-H` just after it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed - although it unfortunately confirmed that correct header file is being loaded and therefore I'm much deeper in dung than I feared.